# Does std::map support caching?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

For example:

**code1:**

```
if((iter = map.find(key)) != map.end()) {
    return iter->second;
}
return 0;
```

**code2:**

```
if(map.count(key) > 0) {
    return map.at(key);
}
return 0;
```

**code2** is much more simpler, but both `map.count()` and `map.at()` cost O(logn) time. Does `std::map` provide a feature that stores the last search item in cache and make searching same item faster, or does it just perform a second search in the whole map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does a search through the whole map, there is no caching being done - or at least, the Standard does not mandate any and I would say no implementation does it, because *all* clients of such an implementation would have to pay for the possibly undesired overhead of updating the cached information after each insertion/removal.

The first approach is the idiomatic way to determine whether a key/value pair is contained in a map (just mind the fact that `operator ->` should be used instead of `operator .`, since what you get from `find()` is an iterator, and the assignment to `iter` should be outside the `if` condition):

```
auto iter = map.find(key);
if (iter != map.end()) {
    return iter->second;
}
```

Comment: +1 Though splitting the condition in the first example into two lines would be clearer IMO.

Comment: @AndyProwl: The proposed retrieve function does the same thing as std::map::at (since C++11)

Comment: @dalle: Hm, you're right. I don't know how I could overlook it, thank you for mentioning it. I will remove that part

Comment: @rhalbersma: Not that I would dare opposing Sutter and Alexandrescu, but that mostly depends on the user's requirements I would say, and on how you define preconditions. That's why the Standard Library offers a throwing and a non-throwing alternative.

Comment: Yes I see now, that's why `at()` has the precondition that the element is there. The raw `find()` and `operator[]` do not. (I wrote my deleted comment during your update).

Comment: The first approach violates every coding guideline I have ever seen.  You _never_ change state in the condition of an _if_.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Not sure what you mean here. Who is changing state?

Comment: @AndyProwl There's an assignment in his `if`.  Assignment changes state.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh, ok. Yes, in the previous edit of my answer I did correct that, but then I rolled back and forgot to mention it. Edited again

Answer (score 4):

No, none of the C++ Standard Library implementations use caching, as far as I know. C++11 requires that containers are thread-safe for multiple readers. And in order to accomplish that the access to the cache need to be synchronized. That will result in a speed penalty, even though you don't want it. A standard practice of C++ is that you should not pay for anything you don't explicitly need or want.

Comment: Is std::map guaranteed to be threadsafe for multiple readers (assuming no writers) by the standard? Otherwise that argument makes little sense.

Comment: @Zarat: Yes according to C++11 it is.

Comment: So the conclusion is since the standard requires thread safety for this scenario, the caching would need to be threadsafe too, which would slow down callers who don't want/need it.

Comment: @Zarat: Clarified what I meant with "not good for multithreading".

Answer (score 1):

It could, but none that I know of do.  The idiomatic solution is
thus to use a variable:

```
auto results = myMap.find( key );
return results == myMap.end()
    ? NULL
    : &results->second;
```

Short, clean and easily understandable.  (And it avoids the multiple returns which make reasoning about the program correctness so difficult.)

Answer (score 1):

Something that was not mentioned, is that although there is no software caching of the search, there will probably be hardware cache of the pointers along the search path (searching a tree), so a second search immediately after the first one should be much faster.